# Is there user agent detection code for none smartphones out there?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect, mobile, user-agent

I'm looking to write an ASP.Net MVC ActionFilter to redirect users of mobiles that aren't in the ambiguos smartphone category to our WAP site. Does anyone know of such code out there?

I've found http://detectmobilebrowser.com/, http://mdbf.codeplex.com/ and http://www.51degrees.mobi/Products/NETMobileAPI already. I prefer the first one's simple use of the useraget as this is a low priority redirect but it doesn't distingues between mobiles and smartphones.

Thanks,
Denis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've only used the MDBF for detecting mobile devices but there is a good example if you download the latest version of nerd dinner from [Codeplex](http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/). This has a mobile view engine set up to show you how its down. Also Scott Hanselman put an example on his blog [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MixMobileWebSitesWithASPNETMVCAndTheMobileBrowserDefinitionFile.aspx).